# PHP Print Date data from database for each date

Tags: php, ms-access

I have a database called `Holidays` which has a date field to save holiday date called `STARTTIME`, and a duration field to save how many days is the holiday called `DURATION`. I want to collect all data from that table between some month and year, and print the date 1 by 1.

For Example, here's my data at database:

```
STARTTIME  | DURATION
2016-12-09 | 1
2016-12-15 | 5
```

How to print it in php 1 by 1 per date? So it will result:

```
2016-12-09
2016-12-15
2016-12-16
2016-12-17
2016-12-18
2016-12-19
2016-12-20
```

My code now is like this:

```
//startDate and endDate is get from my filter, this is only for example 
$startDate = '2016-01-01';
$endDate = '2016-01-31';
$sqlHol = "SELECT STARTTIME, DURATION FROM HOLIDAYS WHERE DATEVALUE(STARTTIME) BETWEEN DateAdd('m',-1,#$startDate#) AND #$endDate#";
$queryHol = $db->query($sqlHol);
$hols = $queryHol->fetchAll();
echo '<br />';
//testing to print out array result
print_r($hols);
//looping through data from database
foreach($hols as $hol)
{
    for($i=1; $i <= $hol[1]; $i++)
    {
        echo '<br />';
        $due = date_create($hol[0]);
        echo date_format($due, 'Y-m-d');
        $due = date_add(date_create($hol[0]), date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 days'));
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

And here's my result (the date doesn't increment):

```
2015-12-09

2015-12-15

2015-12-15

2015-12-15

2015-12-15

2015-12-15

2015-12-15
```

Anyone know how to create an output like I need?

Comment: You have two `<br>` tags in your for loop, try removing the first one.

Comment: Also don't make a habit of executing queries this way, it's insecure. Search PDO.

Comment: @lampwins sorry, it's just for enter... the problem is my date isn't counting... as You can see it always 15... I can't use PDO, I don't know why if I use ms.access I can't use PDO... and this apps only use for a person, so I don't really thought about secure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are writing the due date before you increment it. Try using the loop counter as a way to keep track of how many times you have incremented the date.

```
foreach($hols as $hol)
{
    for($i=0; $i <= $hol[1]-1; $i++)
    {
        echo '<br />';
        $due = date_create($hol[0]);
        $due = date_add(date_create($hol[0]), date_interval_create_from_date_string(i.' days'));
        echo date_format($due, 'Y-m-d');
        echo '<br />';
    }
}
```

Comment: it's better... but the result of mine, at day 9, it counting too... so the result is like these: 2015-12-09, 2015-12-10, 2015-12-11, 2015-12-15, 2015-12-16, 2015-12-17, 2015-12-18, 2015-12-19, 2015-12-20.

Comment: No problem, I fixed this... Your code at: $hol[1]+1 supposed to be $hol[1]. I believe there's no other error... thank you so much

Comment: My mistake, change $hol[1]+1 to $hol[1]-1

Comment: Exactly... I've just wrote that.. :D